# problem to create list of 10.000 randome numbers from 1 to 5 with np.random.choice

Tags: python, numpy

not really sure what I'm doing wrong here. 
What I want to do is to use numpy's random.choice to simulate 5 draws from the students array and Repeat to obtain 10,000 additional proportions, where each sample was of size 5. Store these in a variable called sample_props.

```
import numpy as np
students = np.array([1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0])
sample_props = []
n = 10000
i = 0
while i <= n:
    #y = np.random.choice(students, 5)
    sample_props.append(np.random.choice(students, 5))
    i = i+1
print(len(sample_props))
```

Comment: What is this `y = >`? Also `while i >= n:` will never allow you to enter the loop for your values of i = 0 and n=10000

Comment: y is a variable so I can use it later to append it easier. nothing else.

Comment: so you are suggesting I put "i" within the while loop?

Comment: At least it should be while i<=n: and remove > after y =

Comment: ohhh I see my first problem, the list () is a tupple so cant be changed. it should be a [] list. ... for some reason code still not executing correctly

Comment: Did you use i<=n

Comment: now is working! thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Just do:

```
sample_props = [list(np.random.choice(students, size=5)) for i in range(10000)]
```